# Existence of a root

Tags: analysis, functions, roots

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ continuous, such that for every $x$ there is a $y$ such as that $|f(y)|\leq|f(x)|/2$.

Show there exists a $\xi$ such that $f(\xi)=0$

Comment: @OmranKouba True, it should be a $\leq$, let me change this, I think it's only a typo.

Comment: @OmranKouba With the change of $<$ into $\le$, yours should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $|f|$ is continuous, it attains its minimum $m=|f(\xi)|≥0$, by assumption there must be some $y$ with $$m≤|f(y)|\leq\frac{|f(\xi)|}{2}=\frac{m}{2}$$ that is $m\leq0$, or $m=0$, and we are done.

Comment: because m cannot be negative right? because |f(y)|>0 so there exists y such as that f(y)=0. there is no loophole right?

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis, because the minimum of a non-negative function, (here $|f|$,) is non-negative.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** Pick some $x_0 \in [a,b]$. Prove that there exists some $x_n$ such that
$$|f(x_n) | < \frac{|f(x_0)|}{2^n}$$

Now, use the fact that $x_n \in [a,b]$ must have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: +1, 'was too slow :-) (also, use continuity to prove the limit is indeed a root)

Comment: @N.S. Im new to the function-sequence usage. So can you explain me a bit more.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis Continuity tells you that if you have a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \rightarrow \xi$ and $f(x_n)\rightarrow \nu$, then $f(\xi)=\nu$. With $\nu=0$, what you know of $f$ is enough to find such a sequence: start with any $x_0 \in[a,b]$, then you can find $y=x_1$, do it again... Then [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) tells you this sequence has a converging subsequence, let's call it $\tilde{x}_n$. Then $\tilde{x}_n \rightarrow \xi$ and $f(\tilde{x}_n) \rightarrow 0$, so $f(\xi)=0$.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut why $f(x(n)) ->0$ ??

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis By construction of your sequence, using the fact that for any $x_n$, you can find $x_{n+1}$ such that $|f(x_{n+1})|\leq |f(x_n)|/2$. Thus, you have an infinite sequence $x_n$ such that $|f(x_n)|\leq |f(x_0)|/2^n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut aah im stupid i dont really get it.I create a sequence on the [a,b]  area  a random one.then i know that from bolzano theorem that this sequence has a converging sequence  Xn that goes to a random ξ  why should f(xn)  converge to zero? Using that f(x(n+1)<=f(xn)/2  how can i be sure that f(xn) goes to zero?

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis See above. The $x_n$ are not random, but they are guaranteed to exist by your hypothesis on $f$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut i use that $|f(xn)|$ is positive and it is decreasing? So i can say safe that it goes to $0$? (because not every decreasing positive function goes to $0$)

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis No, you are constructing, one by one, a sequence $x_n$ such that not only is $|f(x_n)|$ decreasing, but it also tends to $0$. Because if $|f(x_{n+1})|\leq|f(x_n)|/2$, then $|f(x_n)|\leq |f(x_0)|/2^n$. Notice the $2^n$ in denominator, and a constant in numerator, so the quotient tends to $0$.

Comment: ohhh thanks i got it now.